# Django admin - form validation in admin panel

Tags: django, validation

I hava a problem with form validation. This is a part of my clean method (forms.py - class SiteAddFormFull(forms.ModelForm)):

```
url = self.cleaned_data['url']
if self.check_url_in_database(url) is True:
    errors.append('Url already exists')
if errors:
    raise forms.ValidationError(errors)
return self.cleaned_data
```

This is check_url_in_database method:

```
def check_url_in_database(self, url1):
    if url1[7:10] == 'www':
        url = 'http://' + url1[11:]
    else:
        url = url1.replace('http://', 'http://www.')
    try:
        Site.objects.get(url=url1)
        return True
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        try:
            Site.objects.get(url=url)
            return True
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return False
```

When I create new object (Site) in my django admin it works fine (validates if url exists in database). Problem appears when I try to modify existing object. It throws the same error ('Url already exists'). What is a proper way to validate only new objects?

Comment: As an aside, it's not clear to me what you're trying to do in your first if / else statement. Have you thought about how it's going to work for https://?

Comment: Yes. You are right - I forgot about https. I will correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model form, you can access `self.instance.pk`. If the primary key exists, then exclude it from the queryset.

```
def check_url_in_database(self, url1):
    if url1[7:10] == 'www':
        url = 'http://' + url1[11:]
    else:
        url = url1.replace('http://', 'http://www.')
    sites = Site.objects.all()
    if self.instance.pk:
        sites = sites.objects.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)
    try:
        sites.get(url=url1)
        return True
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        try:
            sites.get(url=url)
            return True
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return False
```